# using @Input for disable/enable a button

Tags: angular

what I want is to change the enable/disable status for a button which is part of my custom component template. this should be done by an @Input and user should be able to do this:

```
<custom-component>
      [disabled]="true"
      [x]="false"
      [y]="false"
</custom-component>
```

I have put 
`@Input('disabled') public _disabled: boolean;`
in my custom component
and also I put
`[disabled]=_disabled` on my button which is in my custom component template.
the problem is that the above method is not working and changing [disabled] attribute does not enable/disable button.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndyl14?embed=1&file=src/index.html

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: the problem is it is not working @alt255

Comment: I cannot find a button in your custom-component

Comment: Can you create a quick demo on stackblitz.com?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you be more specific

Comment: I have put an stackblitz link

Comment: Just don't do it on the root component, and it will work fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwsr4m?file=src%2Fapp%2Froot.component.ts

Comment: please read the documention of angular.
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do it's passiing to the component the status of the `[disabled]` as an `Input()`  and  check that property in the button to change.
If you want to change the disabled of a button you only need to use the `[disable]` property and not the `[attr.disable]`

You can se the example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-55673048?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

I think the below code can also be helpful but it still is not working

```
constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef) {
    var native = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    var myattr = native.getAttribute("myattr");
}
```